# I collected cnosdb trace through jaeger, and found by building a table that the execution plan collected was for query. Is there a problem?

Tags: database, time-series, trace, jaeger, cnosdb

I collected cnosdb trace information through jaeger, and found by building a table that the execution plan collected was for query. Is there a problem?
I modify the configuration information according to the official document, as follows：

```
[trace]
auto_generate_span = false
[trace.jaeger]
jaeger_agent_endpoint = 'http://localhost:14268/api/traces'
max_concurrent_exports = 2
max_queue_size = 4096
```

Then pull up the 3mta 2data cluster through the official script, as follows：

```bash
bash run_cluster.sh
```

Then create a table by writing to the data interface, as follows：

```bash
curl -i -u "root:" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "uber-trace-id: 3a3a43:432e345:0:1" -XPOST "http://127.0.0.1:12002/api/v1/sql?db=usage_schema&pretty=true" -d "CREATE TABLE air (visibility DOUBLE,temperature DOUBLE,presssure DOUBLE,TAGS(station));"
```

Finally, check the trace through jaegerUI, as follows：

```
Limit: skip=0, fetch=5 [time:Timestamp(Nanosecond, None), database:Utf8;N, host:Utf8;N, node_id:Utf8;N, tenant:Utf8;N, user:Utf8;N, value:UInt64;N]
  Sort: user_queries.time DESC NULLS FIRST [time:Timestamp(Nanosecond, None), database:Utf8;N, host:Utf8;N, node_id:Utf8;N, tenant:Utf8;N, user:Utf8;N, value:UInt64;N]
    Projection: user_queries.time, user_queries.database, user_queries.host, user_queries.node_id, user_queries.tenant, user_queries.user, user_queries.value [time:Timestamp(Nanosecond, None), database:Utf8;N, host:Utf8;N, node_id:Utf8;N, tenant:Utf8;N, user:Utf8;N, value:UInt64;N]
      TableScan: user_queries [time:Timestamp(Nanosecond, None), database:Utf8;N, host:Utf8;N, node_id:Utf8;N, tenant:Utf8;N, user:Utf8;N, value:UInt64;N]
```

Isn't this the execution plan of the query? Is there a problem with the collected information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the jaeger configuration later. By default, it is not displayed in descending order of time. After that, it is normal to check the jaeger log in descending order of time for each operation.